# How to create a Teamcity build trigger that will run job B once per week, after job A finished, where A runs daily

Tags: scheduled-tasks, teamcity, jobs

I have some Teamcity jobs created.
One of those jobs, let's call it `job A`, has a schedule trigger, running daily at 7:00 am.

Now I have another one, `job B`, that I want to run once per week, but only after `job A` ran.

Given that `job A` takes about 30 seconds to run, I know I can create a schedule trigger for `job B`, that will run on every Monday, at 07:10 am.

I also know I can create a Finish Build Trigger, making sure that `job B` runs after `job A` ran, but it will run every day(because `job A` needs to run every day)

I'm trying to find a way to combine these, and come up with some sort of trigger that does something like this:

- runs `job B` once per week(say Monday morning), after `job A` ran.

Could someone nudge me in the right direction? Or explain to me if/why what I'd like to do is a no-no. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the feature called [Snapshot Dependency](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/cloud/2020.2/dependent-build.html#DependentBuild-SnapshotDependency) fits well into your scenario.

To tell it short, you can link the two jobs you have with the snapshot dependency. In your case, `job B` will "snapshot-depend" on `job A`. In my experience, it works best if both jobs use the same VCS root, that is, work with the same repository.

`Job A` is configured to run daily and `job B` is configured to run weekly (via regular scheduled triggers). When job A is triggered, it doesn't affect job B at all. On the other hand, when job B is triggered, it tries to find whether there's a suitable build of A by that time. If the two jobs work with the same repo, and the `Enforce revision synchronization` flag is ON, this means it will try to find the build of A of that same source code revision.

[image]

If there's a suitable build of A, it won't trigger a new one and will just build B. If there's no suitable build of A, it will first trigger A, and then trigger the build of B.

Comment: Is there a way to add some wait time b/w the jobs 
Assuming the build 'A' finished successfully but I want to wait for let's say 30 min before B starts
how would that be achievable? without blocking the runners for staying ideally

Comment: I'm not aware about any built-in possibility to achieve this. The only thing that comes to my mind is sleeping for X minutes as a very first step of B, but you've already mentioned this option as not appropriate.

Comment: Another way that comes to my mind is using Teamcity Rest API 
But trying to find out if is there any way to push the job to build a queue with a specific timing using Rest API from TeamCity.